# How Do I Get a Place ID from an FTID Using Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps

I am getting an FTID from a expanding a short URL sent to my iOS application.  It has an FTID.  How can I get a place ID from this using the Google Web API?  I tried just using the address returned and searching, but it's really hit and miss.  It seems I should be able to get the place ID directly from the FTID somehow.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found from another similar post on CID that you can pass the second part of the FTID to this API function directly...

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?cid=0x6d5f6fcf117bf3c9&key={MyKey}](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?cid=0x6d5f6fcf117bf3c9&key=%7BMyKey%7D)

To return the Place ID.